# Update <select> color using CSS, dependent on chosen option

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I have a `<select>` dropdown, I can set the colors of each of the options via CSS; however, the option's CSS isn't carried over when it's picked/set as the "selected" value of the dropdown.

I.e. If the `#default` option's CSS is *"color:red"* and it's selected, the option's color is red in the dropdown, but once clicked/selected, it uses the CSS of the `<select>` property, which is black. The fact that it uses the select's CSS is fine, but it needs to change color depending on the chosen `<option>` color.

I've done the following in Javascript + JQuery to get around it, but I just wanted to know whether there was a way of achieving this without the use of JS. I saw an example using the "required" parameter of the dropdown and setting the default's value to NULL, however, I'm likely to allow the submission of this form with some default/blank fields, and want a uniform feel to the site's menus.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/179011/

CSS:

```
option {color: green;}
#default {color: red;}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="select">
  <option value='-1' id="default">Please select option</option>
  <option value='1'>One</option>
  <option value='10'>Ten</option>
  <option value='100'>One Hundred</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sel = $('#select');
  sel.css('color', 'red');
  sel.change(function() {
    if (sel.val() != -1) {
      sel.css('color', 'green');
    } else {
      sel.css('color', 'red');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Without jQuery  it's not possible.

Comment: The `<select>` tag is one of the most difficult to customize, save yourself  some headache and use a plugin.

Comment: As @zer00ne has mentioned, the `<select>` is a very challenging element to customise, especially if you want to keep it cross-browser compatible. You better try to create a custom element, and then pass the value to an hidden input field.

Comment: Thanks for that, all. In that case, if I foresee needing more functionality like this going forward, I'll start to look into plugins for select. @Adriano, would you mind expanding a bit on what you meant by "pass the value to a hidden input field"?

Comment: You can do `<select onchange="myFunction()">` and assign the value of your "select" to an hidden text input field which is going to be sent on submit. See this example: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onchange.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not be possible in any other way.

CSS / HTML is declarative. They are not dynamic in nature and have no support for dynamic styling (apart from what you can achieve using pseudoselectors and attributes). For that, you need to interact with the DOM using JS/jQuery.

There are a number of plugins available to customize the select element. Check them out to see if any of those have support for what you're looking for. Here are some references
https://www.sitepoint.com/13-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/
https://www.learningjquery.com/2017/09/20-impressive-jquery-plugins-to-replace-the-html-select-box